# How to get the name of students in a certain section

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I get the name of students by using the section and year_level as arguments? Below is the ERD of my database.

[image]

Comment: -1 -- What have you tried?  How could anyone actually upvote this?

Comment: @sgeddes I've tried what DiogoSantana said below and it worked but how can I do it when I don't know the section_id?, just the section and year_level.

Comment: The ERD diagram provides a lot of valuable detail. But...  [**What have you tried?**](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)  Where's the SELECT statement you tried?

Comment: @spencer7593 I've tried what DiogoSantana said below and also tried this : select username from users, sections, students where users.id = students.user_id and sections.id = 13

but I want to know how to do it if I don't know the sections_id

Comment: @sgeddes I upvoted because to me it's a legitime question even if he didn't try nothing.

Comment: @PercivalMicael: There doesn't appear to be a column named `id` in the `sections` table. And ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operations, use the `JOIN` keyword and move the join predicates to an `ON` clause. After all, it is 2014. (A.D.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select u.fname
from users u
join students s on u.user_id = s.user_id
join sections sec on s.section_id = sec.section_id
where sec.section_id = 1
  and sec.year_level_section = 1
```

You don't even need to join level table. Actually, you don't need that table at all.

Comment: is there a way to do it when i don't know the sec.section_id, when all I know is the year level and section.

Comment: What do you mean about section? if you know the section you should know its id.

Comment: @DiogoSantana: I think he means he wants an equality predicate on the `section` column, rather than the `section_id` column. It's possible that `(year_level, section)` tuple is not unique, and this would be returning students from multiple section_id.

Comment: So are you telling me that I should do two queries?

first I should get the section_id?

    select id from sections where section = 1 and year_level = 1

then when I've known the section_id that's when I'll get the users with this:

    select u.fname
    from users u
    join students s on u.id = s.user_id
    join sections sec on s.section_id = sec.id
    where sec.id = 13
      and sec.year_level = 12
      and sec.section = 1

Comment: @PercivalMicael: Uhhh, no. I don't think anyone is telling you that.